# TotalSearchResults vs Hits in Sitecore Linq to search

Tags: c#, linq, sitecore, sitecore7

When I perform a query with faceting in Sitecore 7, I get a different number for TotalSearchResults and Hits().Count(). Does anyone know why the difference exists? The TotalSearchResults is always higher.

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Language.Equals(computedLanguage)
                && (x.PageTitle.Contains(text)
                || x.PageContent.Contains(text)
                || x.PageHeading.Contains(text)
                || x.PageSummary.Contains(text)
                || x.Content.Contains(text)
                || x.Content_1.Contains(text)
                || x.Content_2.Contains(text)
                || x.Content_3.Contains(text)
                || x.SearchSummary.Contains(text)
              ) && x.Taxonomy == so.Facet);


// get our full count
int hits = query.GetResults().Hits.Count();
int total = query.GetResults().TotalSearchResults;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore will only bring back a certain number of search results.  Whether you are using .Page() or .Take() to limit how many results you are getting back, or Sitecore or your Search API is limiting the maximum number of results that will be returned via settings like ContentSearch.SearchMaxResults, you won't always get all the results back in your dataset.

TotalSearchResults will show you how many results are possible from your search query.  Hits().Count() is only showing you how many you have access to in your returned dataset.  You will want to use .Page() to get access to the additional search results that are beyond the number of Hits() you are currently getting.

Comment: What about using `query.Count()` ?